# How should I initialize the time in the main function?

Tags: c++, struct

This program should work in Visual Studio, but it's not working. It says I'm doing something wrong with the `time` variable that I declared in the `main` function.

> source_file.cpp(59) : warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'time' used

I know I should initialize `time` but I have no idea how to do that.

When I tried

```
input time (0,0, ' ')
```

It showed more errors.

> source_file.cpp(43): error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'input'
>
> source_file.cpp(43): note: No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous

Also, my coding style is messy so I'm sorry for that. It's not because I'm lazy but I'm a beginner and I love loops and conditional statements.

```
struct input
{
    char ampm;
    char dayNight;
    int hour;
    int minute;
};

input take ( input );
input convert ( input );
void give ( input );

int main ()
{
    input time(0,0,'');
    char ans = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int morea = 0, morep = 0;

    do {
        time = take ( time );
        time = convert ( time );
        give ( time );
        ++count;

        if ( time.ampm == 'a' ) {
            ++morea;
        }
        else if ( time.ampm == 'p' ) {
            ++morep;
        }

        cout << "Do you want to do it again? (y/n)";
        cin >> ans;

    } while ( ans == 'y' || ans == 'Y' );

    if ( ans != 'y' || ans != 'Y' ) {
        cout << "\n\nYou did this program " << count << "times\n";
    }

    if ( morea > morep ) {
        cout << "You converted more AM time";
    }
    else if ( morea < morep ) {
        cout << "You converted more PM time";
    }
    else if ( morea == morep ) {
        cout << "The conversion type was equal";
    }

    return 0;

} //int main

input take ( input time ) {    
    cout << "\nPlease enter 12-hour format or 24-hour format (12-hour = a, 24-hour = p) ";    
    cin >> time.ampm;    

    if ( time.ampm == 'a' ) {    
        cout << "Please enter day or night (day = x, night = y) ";    
        cin >> time.dayNight;    
    }    

    cout << "Please enter the hour   ";    
    cin >> time.hour;

    cout << "Please enter the minute ";    
    cin >> time.minute;

    return time;    
}    

input convert ( input time ) {  
    if ( time.ampm == 'p' ) { 
        if ( time.hour >= 13 && time.hour < 24 ) {    
            time.hour = time.hour - 12;    
        } 
        else if ( time.hour == 24 || time.hour == 00 ) {    
            time.hour = 12;    
        }      
    } 
    else if ( time.ampm == 'a' ) {
        if ( time.hour == 12 && time.dayNight == 'y' ) {    
            time.hour = 00;    
        }

        if ( time.hour == 24 && time.dayNight == 'y' ) {    
            time.hour = 00;    
        }
        else if ( time.hour >= 1 && time.hour < 12 ) {    
            time.hour = time.hour + 12;    
        }
        else if ( time.hour == 12 && time.dayNight == 'x' ) {    
            time.hour = 12;
        }
    }

    return time;   
}    

void give ( input time ) {
    if ( time.ampm == 'a' ) {    
        cout << "The new time in 24-hour format is " << time.hour << ":" << time.minute << endl;    
    }    
    else {    
        cout << "The new time in 12-hour format is " << time.hour << ":" << time.minute << endl;
    }    
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [***Minimal***, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please reformat your code, post the error message and remove using namespace std in a header that doesn't even need it.

Comment: `It says I'm doing something wrong with the time that I declared in the main function.` _What exactly_ is it saying?

Comment: My repect for being aware of the fact that your code is messy. Now please act on it and improve it. If you find it messy you can bet that the nitpicky people here are not fans of it either and that will not put them in a helpful mood. Some might even get really annoyed by "I know my code is horrible to read. I do not bother fixing it however...."

Comment: There are plenty of free auto-formatters - including the one built into visual studio.  The number of excuses to not use it is limited.

Comment: Your problem description and the code you shared don't match. `When I tried input time (0,0, ' ') It showed more errors.` Your code shows the attempt to initialize it, but you're not sharing the "more errors" you got from the code you posted.

Comment: @yunnosch Its not that I dont want to bother fixing it but it's because I'm a beginner and I have limited knowledge how to shorten my coding style. You can see that because I'm using more of the basic loops and basic struct for the program.

Comment: Start with deleting ALL empty lines. Then reintroduce a few which really make the code look better. Then use some linebreaks to keep the code readable without horizontal scrolling. Your indentation seems actually quite OK. If you want my individual preferences (not general SO rule): Keep corresponding `{}` in the same colum. Newline before a `{`.  Keep  `} else` together. Then AFTERWARDS bother about mores subtle style issues like loops. Currently the code is ignored before that level...

Comment: `input` does not have a constructor defined, so `input time(0,0,'');` is not valid syntax for initializing an `input` variable. Use `input time{'\0','\0',0,0};` or simply `input time{};` instead. Or leave it uninitialized (and ignore the warning) since `take()` will overwrite it anyway: `input time;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing an uninitalised variable to your `take` function, when really your `take` function should be *returning* a time value.

Since the purpose of `take` is to let the user input a time value it should not have a time value as its parameter. All it needs to do is return the time value that the user entered.

Like this

```
input take(); // no parameter
input convert(input);
void give(input);

...

int main () {
    char ans = 0;
    ...

    input time = take(); // no parameter

    ...
}

input take () { // no parameter

    input time; // local variable for the users input

    cout << "\nPlease enter 12-hour format or 24-hour format (12-hour = a, 24-hour = p) ";

    cin >> time.ampm;

    ...

    return time; // return the entered time value
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: This answer doesn't really address WHY the errors were happening, only how to rewrite the code to avoid them.